# Rest API to connect (authorize) Google for logged in user

Tags: express, authentication, passport.js, mean-stack, google-oauth

I'm working in an application which uses a REST API using the MEAN stack and [Passport JS](http://passportjs.org) to manage the authentication.

The authentication, we use [JTW](http://jwt.io) tokens for the communication between the backend and frontend. The token is generated based on local username and passwords.

Now I want to 'add' (authorize) the user's Google account to the profile to use with Google calendar API. (using this-> https://github.com/wanasit/google-calendar)

I've already have managed to send the user to the Google authorization page, and get the token back from it. The problem is that when the user gets redirected to the page, it looses the JWT token where I check the user for the request.

Is there any other way to get the current logged in user, or to pass some custom callback authorization header/param when calling the authorize method?

*auth.js:*

```
var googleParams = {
        clientID: config.auth.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.auth.google.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.auth.google.callbackURL
    }
    var googleStrategy = new GoogleStrategy(googleParams, function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        profile.token = token;
        return done(null, profile);
    });
```

*routes:*

```
rotas.get(
    '/google',
    auth.authenticate(), // will check the current user
    auth.isLoggedIn, // make sure the user is really logged in
    auth.authorize('google', { scope: googleScope, passReqToCallback: true }) // redirects to Google to get the token
);

rotas.get('/callback/google',
    auth.authorize('google', { scope: googleScope, passReqToCallback: true })
    auth.authRedirect()
);
```

the `auth.authRedirect()` function above is the closest solution I've found. It's a Express middleware which redirects the user to a known route in the frontend where the user IS authenticated... but then I would not be able to fetch all his Google profile and information I need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was:

1. Authenticate the user making the  request via JWT access_token
2. Get the user's ID and set it to the `state` option's property
3. The user is redirected to the google authorization page and choose the account (s)he wants to connect
4. (S)He gets redirected to my callback url with the `state` query param having the user's id
5. Now I just have to get that id, search the user in the database, and set the data I need from `req.account` which contains the user's openid profile.

```js
var googleScope = ['openid', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];

routes.get(
    '/google',
    auth.authenticate(),
    auth.isLoggedIn,
    function (req, res, next) {
        var _id = '' + req.user._id; // convert to String... _id is an mongoose object
        return auth.authorize('google', { session: false, scope: googleScope, passReqToCallback: true, state: _id })(req, res, next)
    }
);

routes.get('/callback/google',
    function (req, res, next) {
        auth.authorize('google', { session: false, scope: googleScope, passReqToCallback: true })(req, res, next);
    },
    auth.saveUserData()
);
```

```js
saveUserData= function () {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.query.state) {
            var _id = req.query.state;
            User.findOne({ _id, deleted: false, active: true })
                .exec(function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.send(err);
                    }
                    if (user) {
                        user.auth.google = {
                            id: req.account.id,
                            token: req.account.token,
                            email: (req.account.emails.length ? req.account.emails[0].value : null),
                            name: req.account.displayName
                        }
                        user.save(function (err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                res.send(err);
                            } else {
                                res.redirect('/')
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        res.sendStatus(401);
                    }
                })
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(400)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... nice! I didn't know this `state` property. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure the `app.use(session)` its been called before any route.

...

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret'
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

...

rotas.get(
    '/google',
    auth.authenticate(), // will check the current user
    auth.isLoggedIn, // make sure the user is really logged in
    auth.authorize('google', { scope: googleScope, passReqToCallback: true }) // redirects to google to get the token
);

rotas.get('/callback/google',
    auth.authorize('google', { scope: googleScope, passReqToCallback: true })
    auth.authRedirect()
);
```

Your `req.user` won't be `undefined` in this case.

If it doen't work right way, I can put my whole code that I've created here.

Hope it help you! :)

Comment: as far as I know, ```passport.authorize``` and ```passport.authenticate``` are almost identical... the difference is that the ```authenticate``` will set ```req.user``` and ```authorize``` sets ```req.account```
Not sure if it's clear on the question, but what i'm really trying to do is to "reauthenticate" the user using the credentials he/she already have.. like, pass some parameter so I can "authenticate" the callback, get the user and "authorize" the account, saving the google data to the local user profile...

Comment: yes, I tried, but I still can't get the user who made the request to get the autorization from google. Note: I'm not trying to "log in" the user... just connect the google account to the local profile...

Comment: So, you already have the profile data, right? You just logged in, and you want to send the profile data to your front-end, is that right? And once you have the profile data (and the jwt token from google), you want to be able to be authorized to access your own api (with to token). Right?

Comment: The user is logged in using local authentication (username and password).
The flow is something like: User logs in -> click a "connect to google account" button -> the backend checks that the user is logged in -> redirects to Google -> google sends the user to the callback url (where i want to "reautenticate" the user, to save the data to the local profile)

Comment: When you say: "reautenticate the user". You mean the user that has been authenticated with local authentication (username and password)? If yes. Are you loosing the user data? Or are you trying to add some new data on it?

Comment: Exactly. The user has already been authenticated. Before it redirects to google I can access the req.user data and it is there, then when google redirects to the callback url the req.user data is lost and i only have ```req.profile``` with the Google data, so I can't know the local user who made the request to save that data to the database...

Comment: Seems that when google call the callbackURL, it doesn't has the cookie session. In my test here, I got the same behavior. But if I call any other route, the req.user still there.

Comment: I've found that i can pass a "state" parameter with a string value when calling ```authorize()```, so I think I can send the user id there... maybe will be the best solution... just need to figure out how to get it back on the callback

Comment: I made it work for me here. You have to be sure that your `app.use(session)` its been called before any route. I'll update my answer!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it still doesn't solve my problem, since we are not using sessions...

Comment: oh!! I didn't know that. I believe it won't be able to handle this without sessions, because google won't send your parameter back. I think you should update your question.